# MLeap and Spark ML SQLTransformer

Tags: machine-learning, spark-mllib

I have a question. I am trying to serialize a PySpark ML model to mleap. However, the model makes use of the SQLTransformer to do some column-based transformations e.g. adding log-scaled versions of some columns. As we all know, Mleap doesn't support SQLTransformer - see here : https://github.com/combust/mleap/issues/126 so I've implemented the former of these 2 suggestions:

For non-row operations, move the SQL out of the ML Pipeline that you plan to serialize
For row-based operations, use the available ML transformers or write a custom transformer <- this is where the custom transformer documentation will help.
I've externalized the SQL transformation on the training data used to build the model, and I do the same for the input data when I run the model for evaluation.

The problem I'm having is that I'm unable to obtain the same results across the 2 models.

**Model 1** - Pure Spark ML model containing

```
SQLTransformer + later transformations : StringIndexer -> 
 OneHotEncoderEstimator -> VectorAssembler -> RandomForestClassifier
```

**Model 2** - Externalized version with SQL queries run on training data in building the model. The transformations are everything after SQLTransformer in Model 1:

```
StringIndexer -> OneHotEncoderEstimator -> 
 VectorAssembler -> RandomForestClassifier
```

I'm wondering how I could go about debugging this problem. Is there a way to somehow compare the results after each stage to see where the differences show up ? Any suggestions are appreciated.